# Invalid transaction params: params specify an EIP-1559 transaction but the current network does not support EIP-1559(polygon)

Tags: metamask, nft, erc-721, polygon, eip-1559

How to solve the above issue when working on ERC 721 using MetaMask(Polygon network-Metamask). I'm using Metamask version 10.9.2.
https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/82008/chris